# How to reuse jQuery code for a html button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I making different buttons that perform different tasks but their code is the same, the only thing that changes are the variables.

Right now, I have a different block of code for each button. What I want is to use the same code for each button.

This is a button to make the post favorite (that works with the above code)

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="favorite-button" data-is-term="false" name="favorite-post-<?php echo $postid ?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" value="<?php make_post_favorite($post->ID); ?>"/>
</form>
```

My jQuery code for the favorite button:

```
jQuery('#content').on('click', '#favorite-button', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if (jQuery(this).val() == "Favorite") {
        jQuery(this).val("Unfavorite");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).val("Favorite");
    }
    var postID = null;
    //var userID = null;

    postID = jQuery(this).attr('data-post-id');
    //userID = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-id');
    var data = {
        action: 'make_post_favorite_response',
        post_ID: postID         
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: followsys_vars.ajaxUrl,
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            'action' : 'make_post_favorite_response',
            'post_ID' : postID},
        success: function(message) {
            jQuery(this).val(message);
                }
    }); 

});
```

This is a button to follow 'something'

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="follow-button" data-is-term="false" name="follow-user-<?php echo $author_id ?>" data-user-id="<?php echo $author_id ?>" value="<?php follow_user($author_id); ?>"/>
</form>
```

And the jQuery code for the follow button

```
jQuery('#content').on('click', '#follow-button', function(event) { //Using .on will attach the evnt to appended items.

    event.preventDefault(); //This Cancels a link's default action (stops auto top)

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "Follow") {
        jQuery(this).val("Unfollow");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).val("Follow");
    }

    var userId = null;
    var term = null;
    userId = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-id');
    term = jQuery(this).attr('data-is-term');
    var data = {
        action: 'follow_user_response',
        author_id: userId,
        isTerm: term            
    };      
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: followsys_vars.ajaxUrl,
            dataType:"json",
            data: {
                'action' : 'follow_user_response',
                'author_id' : userId,
                'isTerm' : term},
            success: function(message) {
                jQuery('.user-followers .author-id-' + userId).text(message.followers);
                jQuery('.user-following .author-id-' + message.currentUserId).text(message.following);


            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Define JavaScript function and pass it as callback to handlers. :) Pure JS here, has little to do with WP.

Comment: @Rarst can I repost it or move it to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Use a multidimensional array that has all the variances in code for the two buttons. Something like:

```
var myVar = [
['favorite-button', 'Favorite', 'Unfavorite', etc],
['follow-button', 'Follow', 'Unfollow', etc]
];
```

Then use $.each and replace the necessary areas with the appropiate array:

```
$.each(myVar, function(i) {

    jQuery('#content').on('click', '#' + myVar[i][0]', function(event) { 

        event.preventDefault(); //This Cancels a link's default action (stops auto top)

        if (jQuery(this).val() == myVar[i][1]) {
            jQuery(this).val(myVar[i][2]);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).val(myVar[i][1]);
        }
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your event listeners bound to individual buttons to
a single event listener bound to your form, or to a div containing
your form. Inside the listener you'd then basically check the type of
the element that was clicked and delegate the event to a function
written for that particular type of element.

For example

```
function handleButton(event) {
    var postID = jQuery(event.target).attr('data-post-id');
    var response = {};
    if (event.target.id == 'favorite-button') {
        response = addFavorite(postID);
    } else if (event.targe.id == 'follow-button') {
        response = followPost(postID);
    } else {
        // add some default action?
    }
    return response;
}
// #content is a bounding element containing all your buttons
jQuery('#content').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch(event.target.nodeName) {
    case "BUTTON":
        handleButton(event);
        break;
    default:
        handleOtherEls(event);
    }
});
```

This has the advantage that you only add one event listener to the DOM. Your implementation of addFavorite and followPost would likely share a significant amount of code, which you could place in a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just switch to a class-based selector instead of an ID selector. If the button had a class of `follow-button` :

```
<input type="submit" class="follow-button" data-is-term="false" name="follow-user-<?php echo $author_id ?>" data-user-id="<?php echo $author_id ?>" value="<?php follow_user($author_id); ?>"/>
```

Then the jQuery could be called on every button with that class.. and the `jQuery(this)` would always refer to the particular button that had been clicked.

```
jQuery('#content').on('click', '.favorite-button', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if (jQuery(this).val() == "Favorite") {
        jQuery(this).val("Unfavorite");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).val("Favorite");
    }
    var postID = null;
    //var userID = null;

    postID = jQuery(this).attr('data-post-id');
    //userID = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-id');
    var data = {
        action: 'make_post_favorite_response',
        post_ID: postID         
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: followsys_vars.ajaxUrl,
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            'action' : 'make_post_favorite_response',
            'post_ID' : postID},
        success: function(message) {
            jQuery(this).val(message);
                }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are having different cases and conditions in both the calls, so you can make a common function(have written called `do_request`) to make Ajax request and can use in both event handlers.

```
var do_request = function(data, success_callback){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "followsys_vars.ajaxUrl",
    dataType:"json",
    data: data,
    success: success_callback
  });
}

jQuery('#content').on('click', '#favorite-button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (jQuery(this).val() == "Favorite") {
    jQuery(this).val("Unfavorite");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).val("Favorite");
  }
  var postID = jQuery(this).attr('data-post-id'),
      data = {
        action: 'make_post_favorite_response',
        post_ID: postID
      };
  do_request(data, function(message) {
    jQuery(this).val(message);
  });
});

jQuery('#content').on('click', '#follow-button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (jQuery(this).val() == "Follow") {
    jQuery(this).val("Unfollow");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).val("Follow");
  }
  var userId = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-id'),
      term = jQuery(this).attr('data-is-term'),
      data = {
        action: 'follow_user_response',
        author_id: userId,
        isTerm: term
      };
  do_request(data, function(message) {
    jQuery('.user-followers .author-id-' + userId).text(message.followers);
    jQuery('.user-following .author-id-' + message.currentUserId).text(message.following);
  });
});
```